# displaying total count of records on a screen with js

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

i am building an application for a school where the users can insert records into a database, and on the home screen, each subject record count should be displayed, however i cant seem to get this working

i have a math api, which lets you insert records into a math table
and i need to display the total count of all records on the home screen of this mobile app

below is some code that comes from my `action.js` file, i had an insertdata method of sorts, and i changed it a little to try to count but it doesnt work, what can i do?

```
 countData: (tableName, data) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {instance} = getState().sqlhelper;
    if (instance) {
      try {
        const transactFunction = (tx) => {
          return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
              let query = null;
              console.log('data', data);
              if (_.isArray(data)) {
                query = squel
                  .select(id)
                  .from(tableName);
                 
              } else if (_.isObject(data)) {
                query = squel
                  .select(id)
                  .from(tableName);
                 
              }
              console.log('query', query);
              const [tx1, result] = await dispatch(
                actions.executeSQLQuery(tx, query),
              );
              console.log('after execute', result);
              
              resolve(result);
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
              reject(error);
            }
          });
        };
        const result = await instance.transaction(transactFunction);
        console.log('result', result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        DropdownService.showAlert('error', 'Error', error);
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: "it doesnt work" is never a good description of a problem. Does the code generate and error message? Which one? Etc. Remember that we cannot run your code to see what happens.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it does nothing at all

Comment: im not sure my query is correct there, but how do you select count in this instance?

Comment: and how would i call this method in my main as the main just has a text label that should show the count

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a while. It is unlikely it does nothing at all, that would only be possible if the code is not used at all. Have you received any messages in the console? Did you try to debug it? See: [Browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware can we take this to chat? may be easier to explain in detail there